# select common values of multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm writing a php code to calculate a value. I have 4 tables with 2 column each. their headers are same. I want to fetch second column of tables that have, say 'MAN', value on their first column:
here are my tables and their dummy values:

[image]

I joined tables on 'dst' with a where clause but the problem arises when a table has does not have a common value and we have not full outer join in mysql. I know we can simulate this with union all operation but I want a efficient way to do this.
here is my try:

```
select t1.dst, t1.pay as pay, t2.pay as pay2, t3.pay as pay3, t4.pay as pay4 from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.dst = t2.dst left outer join t3 on t3.dst=t2.dst left outer join t4 on t1.dst=t4.dst where t1.dst='man';
```

it's dummy because left outer join is not true for this purpose except special cases.

actually I want this:

[image: this]

Comment: Union all rather than join? How do you want your output to appear?

Comment: @P.Salmon I want to get a table with cols. header of each cols is name of the table and its value is the pay value for, for example 'man'.

Comment: Do you want ALL table names and a zero value if MAN does not exist in that table OR do you want only the table names where MAN does exist?

Comment: @P.Salmon 'only the table names where MAN does exist' is fantastic! table name with corresponding pay value of 'man'! see! I want to calculate a value using pay for each table that has the specific dst, like 'man', and return cheapest value.

Comment: I'm confused - your last comment contradicts the image you added in your last edit and why would you want to do this at all if all you want to do is find the cheapest value across all tables -

Comment: @P.Salmon I see. each table calculate the value with a unique algorithm. the algorithm uses pay of its table. after calculation each algorithm returns a value. all I want is to know which tables has specific dst value, say 'man'. if a table has not the value on its dst I'll ignore it and I will know that I should not run the algorithm on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First union then pivot

```
drop table if exists t,t1,t2,t3;
create table t  (dst varchar(3),value int);
create table t1 (dst varchar(3),value int);
create table t2 (dst varchar(3),value int);
create table t3 (dst varchar(3),value int);


insert into t values ('abc',10),('man',10);
insert into t1 values ('abc',10),('man',5);
insert into t2 values ('abc',10),('man',10);
insert into t3 values ('abc',10);

select  dst,
          MAX(CASE WHEN tbl = 't' then value end) as t1,
          MAX(CASE WHEN tbl = 't1' then value end) as t1,
          MAX(CASE WHEN tbl = 't2' then value end) as t2,
          MAX(CASE WHEN tbl = 't3' then value end) as t3  
from
(
select 't' as tbl,dst,value from t where dst = 'man'
union
select 't1' as tbl,dst,value from t1 where dst = 'man'
union
select 't2' as tbl,dst,value from t2 where dst = 'man'
union
select 't3' as tbl,dst,value from t3 where dst = 'man'
) s 
group by s.dst;

+------+------+------+------+------+
| dst  | t1   | t1   | t2   | t3   |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| man  |   10 |    5 |   10 | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```